# Similarity Search in langflow

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to create a langflow where I am embedding the csv to ChromaDB, and want to do a similarity search on this DB, based on the dynamic input provided by the user. I dont want to use OpenAI. What component of langflow will be useful after I save the embedding into ChromaDB?

Any help is appreciated.